# Jquery endless scroll load content from other site

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, http-get

Hi I got this jquery thing called [jquery-endless-scroll](https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-endless-scroll). My code looks similar to this:

```
 $(function() {
  $('#list').endlessScroll({
    pagesToKeep: 10,
    fireOnce: false,
    insertBefore: "#list div:first",
    insertAfter: "#list div:last",
    content: function(i, p) {
      $.get('http://google.com', function(data) {
      return '<li>' + data + '</li>'
      });
    },
    ceaseFire: function(i) {
      if (i >= 10) {
        return true;
      }
    },
    intervalFrequency: 5
  });
});
```

My main Problem is the content it should return. The rest is not so important. 
I want it to return the html markup of google.com but instead of returning this markup it returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this using client side Javascript because of Cross-Domain policy issue for security purpose. But if try to read file's content on the same domain your script is running on, then it will work.

You should use [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) - a server side Javascript for such stuff:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/web-scraping-with-node-js/

Comment: Oh well, actually I want to read an html document which is on the same domain "/user/bookmarks/raw" but even if I change the url to this it's still not working / it wasn't working in the past. It just returns undefined

Comment: Try to debug the `data` in console using firebug or chrome inspector.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/peer/jquery-endless-scroll/foo.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. BTW: The file I opened in my browser is file:///home/peer/jquery-endless-scroll/index.html so it is the same domain(at least some kind of).

Answer (score 1):

Your content is not being returned due to same origin policy. You cannot request data from another server.

See notes on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

"Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol."

Comment: See my comment under the first answer.

Comment: As per your comments on the first answer, your problem still lies with the origin policy, even when working locally like you are now.

You will need to test this on a server or else circumvent your browser's security setting